# Button is hiding behind bottom navbar

Tags: android

In my android app I am using bottom navbar and scrollview in my layout but the last element in my layout is hiding behind bottom navbar.

Like an image below:

[image: dfs]

Below is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Add"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

  <ImageView
   android:layout_height="70dp"
   android:layout_width="70dp"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
   />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bImage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/bName"
    android:hint="Book name"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/bSubject"
    android:hint="Subject"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/bStandard"
        android:hint="Standard"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/bCategory"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/bCity"
        android:hint="Search city"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/bPrice"
        android:hint="Price(Optional)"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bacground"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here in screenshot you can see purple button is hiding behind bottom navbar.SOmeone please let me know how can I fix this issue.

**THANKS**

Comment: post XML file code

Comment: you must give us the xml for this.. to say how you did the layout

Comment: Updated with xml code take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"` to your button so it will leave a space under the button so it will scroll enough to see it

Comment: did you have any success?